# Fill a 4x10 range of cells with specific numbers in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to fill a 4x10 or 10x4 range with excel formula. Letter A will appear 5 times, followed by B for 1 time, C for 2 times and D for 2 times, but no column or row should have more than 1 letter. I'm stuck after trying for 2 days. Thank you!

image description :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
sub fill_test()
strt_column=5
row=5
for i=1 to 4
a=sheet1.cells(i+4,3).value
for j=strt_column to strt_column+a
sheet1.cells(row,j).value=sheet1.cells(i+4,2).value
next j
strt_column=j+1
row=row+1
next i
end sub
```

try this...i havent tested the code but i think it will work.....if theres any error comment back....i lll try to fix them...

Answer (score 0):

Alright.... after thinking about how to phrase the question, I finally got an idea. Please see the formula I used (sorry I can't post image yet with low "reputation"). It's not the most elegant way, as I still have to use different formula for line 1 and line 2 to 4. So please share your thoughts! Thanks @SivaprasathV!

For letter A: IF(E$4<=$C5,$B5,"")
For letter B to D: IF(OR(E$4<=SUM($C$5:$C5),E$4>SUM($C$5:$C6)),"",$B6)

Answer (score 0):

setup your output area as shown in the Image, with headers1-10 and rows 1-4. In(1,1) enter

```
=IF(AND(E$1<=SUM($B$1:$B2),E$1>SUM($B$1:$B1)),INDEX($A$2:$A$5,$D2,1),"")
```

and drag to all cells. Make sure the dollar signs are correct. you should have your desired output

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The extra index() is beautiful. Thanks!